# How to install nodemailer in npm?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I typed 'npm install nodemailer'. but doesn't appear node_modules folder and package-lock.json file. What's wrong?

I tried to search.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are in the root directory of the project where you have package.json or if it is a new project then you will have to initilize npm via `npm init -y` then

`npm i nodemailer`